# Taking root with Feynman prescription

Tags: quantum-field-theory, complex-numbers

For the time component of momenta with Feynman prescription like $\sqrt{-p10^{2}-i\delta}$ and $\sqrt{p10^{2}+i\delta}$, how to perform it? Here p10 is the time component of four momentum. Any detailed example on such calculation?

Comment: Do not repost questions.